# How to evaluate the expectation of the exponential of reflected brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

How do you compute this expectation

$\mathbb{E} \left [ e^{\varepsilon|W_t|} \right] $ where $W_t$ is a Brownian Motion

Do I need to expand the absolute value? Can I use the standard Taylor series approach here? I don't know how to expand $e^{\varepsilon|W_t|}$

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is $$2E(e^{\varepsilon W_t}\mathbf 1_{W_t>0})=2\int_0^\infty e^{\varepsilon\sqrt{t}x}\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx=\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks. Why the indicator function?

Comment: Because $|W_t|$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks very much

Comment: Why do we have a 2 on both sides of the equation? Should it not be on only one side?

Comment: Huh? What is $E(e^{\varepsilon W_t}\mathbf 1_{W_t>0})$ to you?

Comment: The expectation from $ \int_\infty^\infty $ and you changed it to $ 2 \int_0^\infty $ because of symmetry